# variance of a sum of independent random variables

Tags: statistical-inference

I don't get why here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error, `T/n = 1/n²*(n*sig²)`

Is there a side knowledge to have here ?

Comment: Do you get that $\text{Var}T=n\sigma^2$ there? And do you get that in general $Var(cX)=c^2Var(X)$ if $c$ is a constant?

Comment: forgotten about Var(cX) rule thanks